# How do I automate the handling of a problem (no network device found) in Ubuntu 10.04 w/ preseed?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-10.04

I have a preseed file that is doing some automation for an installation of Ubuntu 10.04.  At the point where the network hardware is auto-detected, however, it fails to find hardware and displays a message, "No network interfaces detected".  To make a long story short, I don't *care* if it can detect my network interface.  How do I do one of the following:

1. Skip that step alltogether.
2. Handle the error page automagically.

PS.  I found somewhere where it suggested this:
     netcfg/no_interfaces seen true

That didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip network interface,just comment out the lines containing word "netcfg".

Warning: This will not load any network interface (as you are skipping it)

Check with this and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:
`d-i netcfg/enable boolean false`. I found it [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt).